# Is possible create a openbook with lowest fee?

Tags: solana-program

Currently the fees for creating an openbook of a newly launched token are very high, both on raydium and on platforms like dexlab, ranging between 2 and 5 SOL.. It is possible to create an openbook using some script or develop something that makes it cheaper ?

Comment: Are you talking about an openbook market?

Comment: Yes, openbook market

Answer (score 1):

it is in the advanced settings you can make a listing for around 0.2 SOL